# Is it possible to pass a enum through segue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have this prepareForSegue in my first ViewController with a enum in it

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    enum TypeOfSegue {
        case Edit, Create
    }

    if let DestViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController where segue.identifier == "EditItem" {
        let edit = TypeOfSegue.Edit

    }
    if let DestViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController where segue.identifier == "CreateNewItem" {
        let create = TypeOfSegue.Create

    }
}
```

I want to pass the constants edit or create to my DetailViewController. If possible, how can I do this and under what variable will the TypeOfSegue be saved in DetailViewController?

Comment: Optional binding in `prepareForSegue` is bad design since you – the developer – should know exactly from your storyboard the number of segues, the classes of the  destination controllers and the string identifiers so they can never be `nil`. A `switch segue.identifier { .. }` expression is much more effective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a mode property in your DetailViewController

```
class DetailViewController:UIViewController {    
    var mode: TypeOfSegue!
}
```

Next you can populate it

```
enum TypeOfSegue {
    case Edit, Create
}
class ListViewController:UIViewController {

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let destViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController where segue.identifier == "EditItem" {
            destViewController.mode = .Edit
        }
        if let destViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController where segue.identifier == "CreateNewItem" {
            destViewController.mode = .Create
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

You can also implement the `prepareForSegue` method this way

```
enum TypeOfSegue: String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case Edit = "EditItem", Create = "CreateNewItem"
    var description: String { return self.rawValue }
}

class ListViewController:UIViewController {
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        guard let
            destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController,
            identifier = segue.identifier,
            segueType = TypeOfSegue(rawValue: identifier) else { fatalError("Wrong segue") }
        destViewController.mode = segueType
    }
}
```

Comment: For the `rawValue:` method to work, wouldn't you need to define raw values for the TypeOfSegue enum?

Comment: @MikeAtNobel: you are right, I forgot to paste the updated enum definition.